# Duplicate symbol GMLImage

Tags: react-native, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit, react-native-vision-camera

I am setting up react-native app. I use **react-native-vision-camera** and **vision-camera-code-scanner** for QR scanning. However, I want to also add a custom frame processor for **react-native-vision-camera**. When I tried to add pod **TensorFlowLiteTaskVision** like described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/ios), I got the *"duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64"* error.

```
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GMLImage._height' in:
    ./ios/Pods/MLImage/Frameworks/MLImage.framework/MLImage(GMLImage.o)
    ./ios/Pods/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision/Frameworks/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision.framework/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision(GMLImage.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GMLImage._pixelBuffer' in:
    ./ios/Pods/MLImage/Frameworks/MLImage.framework/MLImage(GMLImage.o)
    ./ios/Pods/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision/Frameworks/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision.framework/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision(GMLImage.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GMLImage._sampleBuffer' in:
    ./ios/Pods/MLImage/Frameworks/MLImage.framework/MLImage(GMLImage.o)
    ./ios/Pods/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision/Frameworks/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision.framework/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision(GMLImage.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GMLImage._orientation' in:
    ./ios/Pods/MLImage/Frameworks/MLImage.framework/MLImage(GMLImage.o)
    ./ios/Pods/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision/Frameworks/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision.framework/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision(GMLImage.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GMLImage._width' in:
    ./ios/Pods/MLImage/Frameworks/MLImage.framework/MLImage(GMLImage.o)
    ./ios/Pods/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision/Frameworks/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision.framework/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision(GMLImage.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GMLImage._imageSourceType' in:
    ./ios/Pods/MLImage/Frameworks/MLImage.framework/MLImage(GMLImage.o)
    ./ios/Pods/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision/Frameworks/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision.framework/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision(GMLImage.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_GMLImage._image' in:
    ./ios/Pods/MLImage/Frameworks/MLImage.framework/MLImage(GMLImage.o)
    ./ios/Pods/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision/Frameworks/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision.framework/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision(GMLImage.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMLImage' in:
    ./ios/Pods/MLImage/Frameworks/MLImage.framework/MLImage(GMLImage.o)
    ./ios/Pods/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision/Frameworks/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision.framework/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision(GMLImage.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GMLImage' in:
    ./ios/Pods/MLImage/Frameworks/MLImage.framework/MLImage(GMLImage.o)
    ./ios/Pods/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision/Frameworks/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision.framework/TensorFlowLiteTaskVision(GMLImage.o)
```

Looks like, both MLImage (which is dependency pod for vision-camera-code-scanner through "GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning") and TensorFlowLiteTaskVision  have the same symbol GMLImage. I checked source files and GMLImage header file is really the same in both pods.

Any ideas how to solve/avoid this?

I tried removing one pod and then another. If there is only one of the pods present, works like it should.